# Want to convert "GdkPixbuf" to "GtkSelectionData" object

Tags: c++, c, gtk, clipboard

I want to convert my pixbuf to "GtkSelectionData" so, how can I convert it in c++ ?
Below is my sample code.

```
clipboard   =   gtk_clipboard_get_for_display (gdk_display_get_default (),
                                                     GDK_SELECTION_CLIPBOARD);
                GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
                pixbuf = gtk_clipboard_wait_for_image ( clipboard );

                if ( pixbuf != NULL )
                {
                    int width, height;
                    width  = gdk_pixbuf_get_width (pixbuf);
                    height = gdk_pixbuf_get_height (pixbuf);
                    //printf("width : %d", width);
                    GtkSelectionData *selectionData;
                gtk_selection_data_set_pixbuf(selectionData,pixbuf);
                g_object_unref (pixbuf);

                 }

Error: cannot convert ‘GdkPixbuf* {aka _GdkPixbuf*}’ to ‘GtkSelectionData* {aka _GtkSelectionData*}’ in initialization
```

Thanks, Jimit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Selections.html#GtkSelectionData), you'll see that there's a function

```
gtk_selection_data_set_pixbuf(GtkSelectionData*, GdkPixbuf*)
```

which does exactly what you want.

The question then is, where do you get the `GtkSelectionData` from? The answer is that usually, when a drop happens (or middle-click is pressed), GTK runs a callback giving you the selection data pointer and asking you to fill it in with the actual bytes that should be transferred.

But the whole drag and drop/clipboard stuff is horribly complicated in GTK. There are a couple of tutorials on the Gnome wiki which help though, I'd suggest having a read of them :-)

Comment: @Trishtan I am copying an image and get it into pixbuf now, I want to transform that pixbuf to "GtkSelectionData" object..will above function help me out for the same?

Comment: `GtkSelectionData` is a struct which holds a pointer to the data you want to transfer, plus other metadata like the type and size and so on. The above function will store the pixbuf pointer in the selection data struct, telling GTK "this is the raw data I want to transfer". But you need to have been handed the selection data by a GTK callback in the first place, so all the other metadata is already filled out correctly. You very rarely need to create a `GtkSelectionData` yourself.

Comment: Tristan told you that you need to get the SelectionData pointer from somewhere, you can't just create it. You haven't shown or told what you actually want to do so we're just guessing but if you e.g. want to copy the pixbuf to a clipboard, then this code would go into a GtkClipboardGetFunc callback that is then connected with gtk_clipboard_set_with_data().